# how to make the timer stop automatically in react. Example: When it reaches 100 it will stop

Tags: reactjs

[image]

```
export const SliderComponent= ({progress, setProgress}) =>{

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) =>prevProgress + 30);
    }, 1100);  
    
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <LinearProgressWithLabel value={progress} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Here my code. how to make the timer stop automatically in react. Example: When it reaches 100 it will stop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please also check [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `ref` [variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for your intervalId. All you need to do is run an effect which runs after every render where `progress` changes. If `progress` is greater than equal to 100, you can clear the interval.

```
export const SliderComponent= ({progress, setProgress}) =>{
  const [progress,setProgress] = React.useState(0);
  const timerRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) =>prevProgress + 30);
    }, 1100);  
    
    return () => {
       clearInterval(timer.current);
    };
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
  if(progress >= 100) clearInterval(timer.current);
  },[progress]); 

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <LinearProgressWithLabel value={progress} />
    </Box>
  );
}
```